# Can ubuntu-precise tag be merged into ubuntu-12.04 tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, synonym-request

Precise Pangolin is the code name for Ubuntu 12.04 development. As such, it is redundant to have both the tags [ubuntu-precise](/questions/tagged/ubuntu-precise) and [ubuntu-12.04](/questions/tagged/ubuntu-12.04). I suggest ubuntu-precise tag be merged into ubuntu-12.04.

On a similar note, [ubuntu-lucid](/questions/tagged/ubuntu-lucid) can be merged into [ubuntu-10.04](/questions/tagged/ubuntu-10.04).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I merged them... and made them synonyms (which is what really addresses the redundancy part).

Comment: Oh yes, tag synonyms. Thanks!